# How To Install Solidity Compiler and Remix?

Tags: cmd, ethereum, solidity

I am really confused. I'm new to Ethereum. I have tried watching videos and I have got a vague idea of it, I have tried installing remix via CMD but every time I put:

```
npm install -g solc
```

into CMD it always comes out with this error:

```
'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I'm using Windows 10.

Thanks :)

Answer (score -3):

If you are new, why not trying the web version first?

https://remix.ethereum.org/

To answer your question, to install npm packages, you need to install npm first.

https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm

Comment: I have installed npm and finally the original command I mentioned in my question has done something: 
C:\Users\DEVICE NAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\solcjs -> C:\Users\DEVICE NAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\solc\solcjs
+ solc@0.6.3
updated 1 package in 1.815s

What does this mean and what am I supposed to do next?

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly?

Answer (score -3):

To install solc - Solidity Compiler over npm you need to install **node package manager** first.

here are the links

https://nodejs.org/en/download/

https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm

https://www.npmjs.com/package/solc